# Histogram not plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

Good afternoon,

I'm newbie here. I am trying to plot a histogram of spread returns, however, matplotlib rejects to plot the histogram without a corresponding error. Would you be so kind to explain, where is my mistake in the code. Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

goog = web.DataReader('GOOG', data_source='google',
start='3/14/2009', end='4/14/2014')
goog.tail()
goog['Ret'] = ((goog['Close'] - goog['Close'].shift(1)) /
                goog['Close'].shift(1))*100


goog[['Close','Ret']].tail()

WY = web.DataReader('WY', data_source='google',
start='3/14/2009', end='4/14/2014')
WY.tail()
WY['Ret'] = ((WY['Close'] - WY['Close'].shift(1)) /WY['Close'].shift(1))*100
WY[['Close','Ret']].tail()

a=goog['Ret']
a = a[~np.isnan(a)]
b=WY['Ret']
b = b[~np.isnan(b)]

%matplotlib inline 


my_array = [i/m for i,m in zip(a, b)]


plt.hist(my_array, bins=25)
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.xlabel('value')
plt.ylabel('frequency')
plt.title('Histogram')
```

Comment: I suspect it's because you need to tell matplotlib to show you your figure. Try adding `plt.show()` at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

That's is because you have `inf` values in your array.

You can fix this if you prevent 0 division:

```
my_array = [i/m for i,m in zip(a, b) if m!=0]
```

or with:

```
my_array = my_array[~np.isinf(my_array)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I don't sure that you want to plot, but saw that you were zipping two list with two columns, then you can plot this with hist()
There are another error in your code I change the line 10, `goog['Ret']=((goog['Close'].shift(1)))` 
and the line 40 by

```
plt.hist(a, bins=25)
plt.hist(b, bins=25)
```

The problem with this line 40 is parameter `my_array`.

`a` and `b` are dictionaries when you do `my_array = [i/m for i,m in zip(a, b)]` you're making a list without labels to the histogram.

Then finally the code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

goog = web.DataReader('GOOG', data_source='google',
start='3/14/2009', end='4/14/2014')
goog.tail()
#print(goog['Ret'])
goog['Ret']=((goog['Close'].shift(1)))
#goog['Close'].shift(1))*100

#print(((goog['Close'].shift(1)),goog['Close'].shift(1))*100)
#print(((goog['Close'].shift(1))))#,goog['Close'].shift(1)))


goog[['Close','Ret']].tail()

WY = web.DataReader('WY', data_source='google',
start='3/14/2009', end='4/14/2014')
WY.tail()
WY['Ret'] = ((WY['Close'] - WY['Close'].shift(1)) /WY['Close'].shift(1))*100
WY[['Close','Ret']].tail()

a=goog['Ret']
a = a[~np.isnan(a)]
b=WY['Ret']
b = b[~np.isnan(b)]

#matplotlib inline 


my_array = [i/m for i,m in zip(a, b) if m!=0] # This works too

#print (a)
#print (b)


plt.hist(my_array, bins=25)
#plt.hist(a, bins=25)
#plt.hist(b, bins=25)
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.xlabel('value')
plt.ylabel('frequency')
plt.title('Histogram')
plt.show()
```

I really hope this can help you.

Good luck, and if this help you don't forget accept the answer and/or vote up.

Comment: I'm afraid it makes no sense. Regardless of that fact you re-used my answer.

Comment: I trying to help. I think the goal of the community is resolve the problems together. I correct the original code, then I think that also you have used my corrections, because the original code didn't running. But I think the important is resolve the problems.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't constructive, but your answer doesn't answer the question. Your code may work, but it's because you remove part of the code you didn't understand, and because you applied my answer as if it was yours (problematic). Apart from that, your explanations illustrate that you did not understand what you're doing.